# Combine 3 arrays into One

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I have 3 Queries

```
$this->db->select('count(id) as Lead_Current_Month')->from('admin_lead_distribution');
$result1=$this->db->get()->result();

$this->db->select('count(id) as Lead_Current_Month')->from('level1_lead_distribution');
$result2=$this->db->get()->result();

$this->db->select('count(id) as Lead_Current_Month')->from('level2_lead_distribution');
$result3=$this->db->get()->result();
```

When I print it gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Lead_Current_Month] => 12
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Lead_Current_Month] => 38
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Lead_Current_Month] => 10
        )

)
```

How to combine 3 arrays into one?
I want the result to be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Lead_Current_Month] => 60
        )

)
```

[Lead_Current_Month] => 60(60 is sum all the 3 array values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just sum up the values of the results, and I don't know why you want to store the information in any array/object, just store it in a variable.

```
$sum_result = $result1[0]->Lead_Current_Month + $result2[0]->Lead_Current_Month + $result3[0]->Lead_Current_Month;

echo $sum_result; //will echo 60
```